# see model data from controller in View [sap ui5]

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I've created a JSON model in a controller, and I have nice data list there...
but I do not know how to access this list/model via corresponding view. Help?

Comment: Can you show us some code of your view and controller and where you want to access the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set model in controller:

```
`sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonModel,"NAME");`
```

and get this model in View (JS view) with:

```
`sap.ui.getCore().getModel("NAME");`
```